# Issue regarding Javascript Modular pattern

Tags: javascript, modular-design

I was reading javascript Modular pattern from this url `http://viralpatel.net/blogs/javascript-module-pattern/` and

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247241/Javascript-Module-Pattern
```

and some time confusion arise in my mind. so here i am putting things where i get some confusion. please help me to understand all.

### Question 1

see the below code. all private variable and function declared in module with var keyword. here pub object also declared with var keyword. 
it means pub is private. so when pub is private then how people can call pub related function from out side like below code

**calling syntax**

```
CalcModule.add(2,10);
CalcModule.add(5,15);

CalcModule = (function(){
        var pub = {};
        var mem = new Array(); //private variable

        var storeInMemory = function(val) {  //private function
                            mem.push(val);
                    };

        pub.add = function(a, b) { 
                     var result = a + b;
                     storeInMemory(result); //call to private function
                     return result;
                  };

         pub.sub = function(a, b) {
                     var result = a - b;
                     storeInMemory(result); //call to private function
                     return result;
                  };

         pub.retrieveFromMemory = function() {
                     return mem.pop();
                 };

               return pub;
})();

CalcModule.add(2,10);
CalcModule.add(5,15);
console.log(CalcModule.retrieveFromMemory()); //outputs 20
console.log(CalcModule.retrieveFromMemory()); //outputs 12
```

### Question 2

Separating Module across different JS files: Augmentation

### file1.js

```
var CalcModule = (function($, pub){
                        //jQuery will still be available via $
                        var mem = new Array(); //private variable

                        pub.storeInMemory = function(val){
                                                mem.push(val);
                                            };

                        pub.retrieveFromMemory = function(){
                                     return mem.pop();
                       };

                       return pub;
})(jQuery, CalcModule || {});
```

### file2.js

```
var CalcModule = (function($, pub){
                       //jQuery will still be available via $
                       pub.add = function(a,b){ 
                                     var result = a + b;
                                     pub.storeInMemory(result);
                                     return result;
                                  };

                       pub.sub = function(a,b){
                                     var result = a - b;
                                     pub.storeInMemory(result);
                                     return result;
                                  };

                       return pub;
}(jQuery, CalcModule || {}));
```

see this `function($, pub)` syntax. why dollar sign is there and why pub need to pass there.

### Question 3

what is the difference between module Augmentation and sub module ?

### Question 4

### Extending existing module module

```
var Module1 = ( function (oldModule) {
    var 
    //assigning oldmodule in to a local variable.
    parent = oldModule;

    //overriding the existing privileged method.
    parent.privilegedMethod = function ( ){
         //do something different by overriding the old method.
    };

    //private method accessing privileged method of parent module.
    var privateMethod2 = function ( ) {
        parent.privilegedMethod();//can access privileged method of Module
        parent.publicMethod1(); //can access public method of Module
    }
    return {
        newMethod : function ( ) {
          ///do something for this brand new module.
          ///use some functionality of parent module.
          /// parent.privilegedMethod( );
        }
    };
} )(Module);//
```

Module object is the existing module that I want to extend.

how anyone can understand the above code extend the module. just by this syntax `(Module)` ?

### Question 5

if we write module in 5 separate js file then which file we need load first. what will be the order of loading those module related s file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer 1

Because at the end it's returning `pub` so you'll have access to all its methods

```
CalcModule = (function(){ return pub; }());
CalcModules === pub
```

## Answer 2

```
function($, pub)
```

This is the declaration of the anonymous function that is called at the end of the code

Here we have the effective call passing jQuery and your module

```
(jQuery, CalcModule || {}));
```

#### N.B.

We are passing jQuery as first parameter and CalcModule as second only if exist otherwise an empty object (CalcModule OR {}).
The first time the function is called CalcModule doesn't exist and so you'll end up passing an empty object, the second time CalcModule exist because has been created by the previous call.
This is done to make it order agnostic.

So we can deduce

#### First Call

```
$ === jQuery
pub === {}
```

#### Second and next Calls

```
$ === jQuery
pub === CalcModule
```

You have to pass CalcModule to the function so it can be expanded.

This

```
(function($, pub){...}(jQuery, CalcModule || {}));
```

is exactly equal to this

```
var anonFunc = function($, pub){...};
anonfunc(jQuery, CalcModule || {});
```

## Answer 3

Augmentation: you are adding functionality to the same module

```
pub.add = function(a,b){}
pub.sub = function(a,b){}
```

Sub-Module: you are adding a module to another module

```
subModule.add = function(a,b){}
subModule.sub = function(a,b){}
pub.subModule = function(a,b){ return mySubModule; }
```

## Answer 4

You are passing `Module` but it's creating a brand new module that can USE the `Module` you have passed, this is more like a sort of Inheritance than Augmentation

## Answer 5

Depends, but generally it's indifferent because you're just declaring the functionalities of your Module.
The only case where you need to respect an order is when a functionality construction depends on another functionality of the module.

Comment: 1) if we do not return pub at end then can we access pub from outside.

Comment: 2) what is the meaning of this (jQuery, CalcModule || {}));
first we declare module then we call module where we need to pass name
what is the objective